# set cursor to start of inputbox

Tags: javascript, css, input

I have an input box that is populated with text just after page load.  As shown in the following example.

```js
var someString = "some text that was set after page load.";
document.getElementById("myInput").value = someString;
```

```html
<input id="myInput" autofocus></input>
```

After the text is added, I want to put the cursor at the start of the input instead of the end.  Any advise.

This is a vanilla JS project.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your js like below and it should work fine.

```
 var someString = "some text that was set after page load.";
 var elem = document.getElementById("myInput");
 elem.value = someString;

 if (elem.createTextRange) {
     var part = elem.createTextRange();
     part.move("character", 0);
     part.select();
 } else if (elem.setSelectionRange) {
     elem.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
 }
 elem.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing for modern browsers (anything more recent than IE8), you can use [`setSelectionRange()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange)